# Show and Hide multiple Divs based on click

Tags: javascript

Hey there i have this code that needs to hide and show divs based on the ID. Which works but the issue is i need to be able to hide other DIVS on the page with the same ID.

I know ID's are suppose to be unique but when I try to use querySelectorAll my console says

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'display')"

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'className')

Im also having a hard time just having the first tab only show, right now all content shows until a button is clicked.

EDIT: I found a solution wrapping around the container elements, its not the ideal solution in case something gets added down the road but it works.

Would still love to see a solution to learn from but thanks for those who helped.

```html
<div class="swapMenuBlock">
  <ul class="side bar tabs" id="tab">
    <li class="tabButton" id="tabs1" onclick="showStuff('IV')">Ivs</li>
    <li class="tabButton" id="tabs2" onclick="showStuff('Injection')">Injections</li>
    <li class="tabButton" id="tabs3" onclick="showStuff('NAD')">NAD</li>
  </ul>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Get the tab element
    var btnContainer = document.getElementById("tab");

    // Get all buttons inside with tabbutton
    var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("tabButton");

    // Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
      btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
        this.className += " active";
      });
    }

    // Toggle displays
    function showStuff(id) {
      document.getElementById("IV").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("Injection").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("NAD").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: *"with the same ID"* - are you saying you have more than one element with a specific id?

Comment: IDs do need to be unique - you can use a class or other attribute if you need to, which can be just as easy to access when using `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll`

Comment: You're definition of `current` doesn't make much sense; you are retrieving all elements with the class `active`, removing that class, then adding it back again. The biggest issue here is that you're not checking whether `current` actually contains any elements or not. You're assuming `current[0]` exists.

Comment: If the definition for `current` is actually meant to reference the button you clicked, you would need to change it to reference `this`, or specify a first argument (e.g. `event`) and then reference `event.currentTarget` -> `btns[i].addEventListener(function(event) {...`

Comment: From my understanding, the effect which you want is when one of the `tabButton` is clicked, an `active` CSS class will be added to the `tabButton` and remove the 'active` class from other `tabButton`?

Comment: @Spectric Yes but i want to move to classes as i need to show and hide multiple divs based on whats clicked not just one element.

Comment: @TheKNVB Yes im just adding an active class to the menu for the one clicked that i dont care much about right now, the main goal is to hide multiple divs with the same class based on what is clicked in the tabs menu

Answer (score 0):

IDs must be unique. Instead, give the elements that should be shown/hidden together the same CSS class. Then you can query for all the elements with that class and show/hide them.

EXAMPLE:

```js
let foos = document.querySelectorAll(".foo")
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  foos.forEach(function(el){
    el.classList.toggle("hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<button>Toggle</button>
<div class="foo">foo</div>
<div class="fooBar">fooBar</div>
<div class="foo">foo</div>
<div class="fooBar">fooBar</div>
<div class="foo">foo</div>
<div class="fooBar">fooBar</div>
<div class="foo">foo</div>
<div class="fooBar">fooBar</div>
<div class="foo">foo</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause of **Bug** :-

When your click handler run for first time and search for tags containing an `active` class, gets an empty array because the html has no tag with active class.

Now then

```
var current = [];
current[0] = undefined; 
current[0].className =(undefined).className;

//and the console is showing you this error.
//Uncaught TypeError:
//Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'className')
```

**Solution** :-

Just add a `active` class mannually to any one of the `li` tag.
Like this :-

```
<ul class="side bar tabs" id="tab">
    <li class="tabButton" id="tabs1" onclick="showStuff('IV')">Ivs</li>
    <li class="tabButton" id="tabs2" onclick="showStuff('Injection')">Injections</li>
    <li class="tabButton active" id="tabs3" onclick="showStuff('NAD')">NAD</li>
</ul>
```